# How to store the credentials for a webservice call with basic authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, security

I am fetching some data from a webservice into my web app. 
The company providing the webservice sent me a username and password to access their service. Unfortunately I don't have too much experience with such calls, but it seems to be working so far.

I have something like this:

```
  $scope.getData = function() {

    var usr = "myusername";
    var pwd = "alligator3";
    var url = "https://thewebservice.com/auth/api/";
    var data = mydata;

    $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(usr + ":" + pwd)
      }
    }).then(_success, _error);
  };
```

With this setup you are able to see the credentials just by pressing F12 in the browser and looking at the js File.

How bad is this?

How can I prevent that?

How/where should I store the credentials instead?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is a very bad idea and goes against basically every security standard there is. Don't ever 1) store credentials in plain text 2) store credentials on the client side. If the API you are consuming doesn't support tokens or something then wrap your API call in a function on the server (yours) and have that call out using your plain text credentials to the API (their server) and just pass the result back to the browser (client). Store the credentials as encrypted values somewhere on the server.

Comment: Okay thanks. I knew that I could manage with my own server, but since my app doesn't need one anywhere else, I tried to avoid one. But basically, there is no way to do this on the client side?

Comment: no way that is secure. Nothing on the client side is ever secure and you can never assume that it is.

Comment: Alright, more work then...I'll accept that as an answer if you want to convert it, thank you!

Comment: no need to accept it as an answer, I'm just glad i could help.